# Converted Bookmarklet to Chrome Extension not working

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a bookmarklet which would make all hidden input form fields visible. For ease of access for other users I wanted to convert it to a Chrome Extension.

I used http://sandbox.self.li/bookmarklet-to-extension/ to convert but after installing, it does not function.

If someone could please enlighten me as to what is wrong with the following code:

### Manifest.json

```
{
    "background": {"scripts": ["background.js"]},
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon-128.png",
        "default_title": "WP3"
        },
    "name": "WP3",
    "description": "WP3",
    "icons": {
        "16": "icon-16.png",
        "48": "icon-48.png",
        "128": "icon-128.png" },
"permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*"
],
"version": "0.1",
"manifest_version": 2
}
```

### Background.js

```
 <script>
      chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
      chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: "bookmarklet.js"})
      });
 </script>
```

### Bookmarket.js

```
(function(){var is=document.getElementsByTagName("input");for(i=0;i<is.length;i++){if(typeof(is[i].attributes["type"])!="undefined"&&is[i].attributes["type"].value.toLowerCase()=="hidden"){is[i].setAttribute("type","text");is[i].setAttribute("style","background-color:#000000;color:#FFFFFF");}}})();
```

Comment: There is a HTML `<script>` tag in JavasScript file? That's invalid. Try removing both `<script>` and `</script>`. If it won't help, post an error you get in Chrome Web Tools console after chrome action button is clicked.

Comment: @KonradDzwinel awesome worked like a charm!!

Answer (score 0):

> There is a HTML  tag in JavasScript file? That's invalid. Try removing both <script> and </script>. If it won't help, post an error you get in Chrome Web Tools console after chrome action button is clicked.